# Cannot create django superuser inside virtual environment

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-22.04

Firstly, if I missed finding a solution already posted, I apologize. I really did try figuring this out.

**So here is the command executed:**
"(VENV) user@server:/var/www/html/django-apps/GT1$ python manage.py createsuperuser

**The error returned is:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/django-apps/GT1/manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/www/html/django-apps/GT1/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        main()
    File "/var/www/html/django-apps/GT1/manage.py", line 13, in main
        raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?
```

The virtual environment exists obviously because it's active when I'm trying.

I've deleted the virtual and tried reinstalling. When I do that, I get a message that django is already installed.

That message is:

```
    (VENV) darren@server:/var/www/html/django-apps$ sudo pip install django
    Requirement already satisfied: django in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (4.2.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from django) (0.4.4)
    Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from django) (3.7.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from asgiref<4,>=3.6.0->django) (4.6.3)
    WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

UPDATE:
Here is what I've tried.
I uninstalled django entirely because it was initially installed using sudo which put it in the default Python location.
Now when I try to install it to the virtual environment created it fails.

I'm sure I have a rights issue but don't know how to resolve it.

I created a python_envs folder beneath /var/www to hold the virtuals.
Then created the VENV which now exists as GT_Dev1 under the python_envs folder.
When I attempt to install into the venv I get a permissions error.

I created both the python_envs folder and the virtual using sudo because my user doesn't have permissions in the var/www folder.

Should I delete the both the virtual itself and the envs folder and recreate using sudo? Which I may actually have done, I've type some many commands trying to resolve this I've lost track.

Thanks,
Darren

Comment: Could you try with `python3 manage.py createsuperuser` ? By using specific `python3`.

Comment: I did actually but don’t have the error returned. I’ll do it again and reply. I actually think the error I made was in the initial install. 
I think that “sudo pip install django” installed it in the default Python location and not in the virtual. But I don’t know how to undo that and reinstall in the right place because Python already things it’s there now.

Comment: It shouldn't, because running pip install while being in the virtual environment should not fail if the library is already in your default environment. It's the purpose of environments, being isolated. Maybe try running the pip install in your virtual environment without the `sudo` keyword. I think I remember I had similar problem in the past that using `sudo` into a virtual environment did not work because it was looking in default environment instead.

Comment: So I tried again this morning. Created a new virtual and activated it.
Once active, I tried installing django into it with the following command and result:

(GT_Dev1) darren@server:/var/www/python_envs$ pip install django
Collecting django
 NOTE: ALL OF THE PACKAGES WERE CACHED. DELETED TO SAVE CHR.
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, sqlparse, asgiref, django
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/python_envs/GT_Dev1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typing_extensions.py'
Check the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use Django in VENV? But installed it via `sudo` (with administrative rights). Python does not have enough permissions. Either install Django with crawler rights or run your `manage.py` via `sudo`

Comment: I do and did. So I just completely removed django via sudo.
Now when I try to install directly into the VENV I get a permissions error.

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/python_envs/GT_Dev1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typing_extensions.py'
Check the permissions.